# Proper way to add ID to URL in AJAX/JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax code that gets an array of tasks like this

```
function showTodo(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '?cont=read_rest',
            success: function (data){
                $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (key, value) {
                    console.log(value['todo']);
                    $('#todo_list_ul').append($("<li>" + value['todo'] + "<a href='?cont=update_rest&sequence=' class='todo_update'>update</a> <a class='todo_delete' href=''>delete</a></li>"));
                    //I need to insert value['index'] at the end of a href='?cont=update_rest&sequence='
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

Im new to programming and I dont know why putting another set of '' and adding + value['index'] makes my IDE have errors. What should be the proper way of doing this?

Comment: you could try `"<a href='?cont=update_rest&sequence="+value['index']+"' class='`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly note that you can append the HTML string directly, you don't need to create a jQuery object around it.

To solve the issue you need to arrange the quotes correctly around the string so that the value is concatenated, like this:

```
$('#todo_list_ul').append('<li>' + value['todo'] + '<a href="?cont=update_rest&sequence=' + value['index'] + '" class="todo_update">update</a><a class="todo_delete" href="">delete</a></li>');
```

Alternatively this can be made slightly less verbose by using template literals to create the string. Note that this will not work in any version of IE, though:

```
$('#todo_list_ul').append(`<li>${value['todo']}<a href="?cont=update_rest&sequence=${value['index']}" class="todo_update">update</a><a class="todo_delete" href="">delete</a></li>`);
```